# Extract values from XML string using oracle xml commands

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to extract the values of the attributes `active_ind` and `call_status` from the following string:

```
<INSURANCE_HISTORY active_ind="Y" call_status="A"/>
```

I have sorted this issue with `substring` and `instr`, but need to use XML commands to extract these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath, xquery, i recommend you to read something about these technology.
@ is used to access attribute in xml elment

```
select extract(xmltype('<INSURANCE_HISTORY active_ind="Y" call_status="A"/>'),'/INSURANCE_HISTORY/@active_ind')  active_ind
, extract(xmltype('<INSURANCE_HISTORY active_ind="Y" call_status="A"/>'),'/INSURANCE_HISTORY/@call_status') call_status

 from dual;
```